# Yii2: custom validation for multiple attributes using OR not working

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to write a rule that validates if attribute_a or attribute_b is set;

one of the following attributes must be set : `licitatii_publice` or `licitatiile_atribuite`

The following code does not work;

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class AbonamentValidare extends Model {

    public $licitatii_publice;
    public $licitatiile_atribuite;
    public $zone;
    public $judete;
    public $tari;
    public static $targetAttribute = [];

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['zone'], 'required'],
            [['licitatii_publice', 'licitatiile_atribuite', 'tari', 'judete'], 'safe'],
            ['licitatii_publice', 'validate_tip_licitatie', 'targetAttribute' => ['licitatii_publice', 'licitatiile_atribuite']],
        ];
    }

    function validate_tip_licitatie($attribute, $param) {
        print_r($attribute);
        $this->addError($attribute, 'eroarea');
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'licitatii_publice' => 'lp',
            'licitatiile_atribite' => 'la',
            'tari' => 'tari',
            'judete' => 'judete',
            'zone' => 'zone',
        );
    }

    public function save() {
        return false;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You have to write custom validator

Comment: `validate_tip_licitatie` is the custom validator

Comment: Hope this link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081066/yii-form-model-validation-either-one-is-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what I have done in a case like this is to create the validator like this:

```
................
    return [
                [['zone'], 'required'],
                [['licitatii_publice', 'licitatiile_atribuite', 'tari', 'judete'], 'safe'],
                [['licitatii_publice, licitatiile_atribuite'], 'validate_tip_licitatie'],
            ];
............
    function validate_tip_licitatie($attribute, $param) {
        if(!$this->licitatii_publice && $this->licitatiile_atribuite)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'eroarea');
    }
```

In this way you show both fields with an error.

However I have done this in Yii1, but from what I read Yii2 should be the same. The logic is the same.

If you want to show error only for 1 attribute you can always just use

```
return [
            [['zone'], 'required'],
            [['licitatii_publice', 'licitatiile_atribuite', 'tari', 'judete'], 'safe'],
            [['licitatii_publice'], 'validate_tip_licitatie'],
        ];
```

What you are trying to do is more fancy :), I get that. If you really want to use targetAttribute you might have to do it like this
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/ExistValidator.php

Just build your own validator class.

Well. After reading about the exist validator i believe that is exactly what you need. It has examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to update this answer for Yii2 case.
In Yii2 the validators have a `skipOnEmpty` attribute which is by default set to `true`. This implies custom validators will not be called if the field is empty, which might not be the required behavior, especially in this case where either of one attribute is mandatory. In order to fix this issue we need to set the `skipOnEmpty` to false as shown below.

```
[['licitatii_publice, licitatiile_atribuite'], 'validate_tip_licitatie', 'skipOnEmpty'=> false],
```