# Yii2 model custom validate method / function does not work

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I want to validate my **fine_amount** against 2 input  **date**. But it does not return any error. Without validating this method it saved data. 
I also looked into

[**`Yii2: how to use custom validation function for activeform?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805133/yii2-how-to-use-custom-validation-function-for-activeform) but for me no solution.

Below is my code

**`Controller method`**

```
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $model->payment_date=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($model->payment_date));
    $model->payment_expected_date=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($model->payment_expected_date));

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->payment_date=date('Ymd',strtotime($model->payment_date));
        $model->payment_expected_date=date('Ymd',strtotime($model->payment_expected_date));

        if($model->validate()){
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else{
            $model->payment_date=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($model->payment_date));
            $model->payment_expected_date=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($model->payment_expected_date));

            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

**`My Rule`**

```
['fine_amount' , 'fine_required'] ,
```

**`Validation function`**

```
public function fine_required() {
    $this->payment_date = date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( $this->payment_date ) );
    $this->payment_expected_date = date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( $this->payment_expected_date ) );

    if ( $this->payment_date > $this->payment_expected_date ) {
        if ( $this->fine_amount <= 0 ) {
            $this->addError ( 'fine_amount' , 'Fine Amount Must be add.' );
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what does not work what behaviour do you get when you submit the form ? add your `controller/action` too

Comment: I want to check if payment date greater than expected date then it must be input some positive value but it does not validate this. I mean without this validation data save.

Comment: positive value for `fine_amount` ? and what format are the `payment_date` and `payment_expected_date` posted via form ?

Comment: yes but only when expected_date is less than payment_date

Comment: date format is dd-mm-yyyyy but I convert that & if I exit in this function it does not effect

Comment: you dont need to convert the date for comparison now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`conditional validation`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation) for your case, use `when` and `whenClient` respectively see below add to your rules section and remove any other validations. This will handle frontend and backend both validations

```
[ 'fine_amount' , 'required' , 'when' => function($model) {
        if ( $model->payment_date > $model->payment_expected_date ) {
            if ( $model->fine_amount <= 0 ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } , 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {

    var d1 = new Date($("#' . Html::getInputId($this, 'payment_date') . '").val());
    var d2 = new Date($("#' . Html::getInputId($this, 'payment_expected_date'). '").val());
    if(d1>d2){
        if(value<=0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}' , 'message' => 'Fine Amount Must be add.' ] ,
```

**EDIT**

Replaced `strtolower ( \yii\helpers\StringHelper::basename ( get_class ( $this ) ) )` with `Html::getInputId` as it is more suitable for this case.

Comment: how I pass model data to this function?

Comment: which one `when` or `whenCLient` ? @Destroyer.0211

Comment: look into the documentation here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation

Comment: for when & whenCLient both

Comment: `$model` is passed as a parameter for `when` you can use it there, and in `whenClient` you can use `$this` @Destroyer.0211

Comment: ['fine_amount','required', 'whenClient'=>function($model)
            {
                $payment_cr_date=date('Ymd',strtotime($model->payment_date));
                $payment_cr_expected_date=date('Ymd',strtotime($model->payment_expected_date));

                if ($payment_cr_date > $payment_cr_expected_date) {
                    if($model->fine_amount <= 0 || empty($model->fine_amount)){
                        $model->addError('fine_amount', 'Fine Amount Must be add.');

                    }

                }

            }],

Comment: you dont need to do that , i have already written for you the validation,

Comment: donot do that just use it as is you dont need to convert date

Comment: message does not show by that, if i keep blank then only show message

Comment: i cant get what you are saying the message will be shown for the active form frontend validation and after submit on the server side too i have tested is and it works fine you dont have to add any other thing or check. it is impossible that the message doesnot show up , you should call `$model->validate()` or `$model->save()` and it will automatically trigger

Comment: now it does not save but no it does not show any message.

Comment: @Destroyer.0211 its not saving because you have the wrong format you need to format your dates before you call save not inside the validation but insude the controller action .

Comment: you should look into documentaion to onow how to work with models

Comment: Sorry maybe i can not properly describe you. I format date and save date without my validation format. But when I try to validation it does not showing message & if I do $model->save(false) then it save.

Comment: @Destroyer.0211 add your controller action code by editing you question, i will look into it