# One of to dropdownlists must be required

Tags: javascript, yii2, rules, required

Hi i have 2 dropdownlsits:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'Rel_User')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(UrUser::find()->orderby('Surname')->all(), 'Id', 'fullName'),
    'language' => 'pl',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Wybierz użytkownika ...')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Rel_Category')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(SmUserCategory::find()->orderby('Name')->all(), 'Id', 'Name'),
    'language' => 'pl',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Wybierz kategorię ...')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>
```

And i want to make one of them required if second of then is not selected. So if user not select both of them it should show message under two of them but if user select one it should save my model.
I tried to do that with rules:

```
 [['Rel_User'], 'required', 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {return $('#banner-rel_category input[type=dropdown]:checked').val() == null}"],
 [['Rel_Category'], 'required', 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {return $('#banner-rel_user input[type=dropdown]:checked').val() == null}"],
```

but now 2 of then is all time required. What can i do to required one of then?
my action create in ctrl

```
 public function actionCreate() {
            $model = new Banner();
            $model->scenario='create';
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $model->File = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'File');
                if ($model->save() && $model->upload() && $model->validate()) {
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                }
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                            'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

My rules now:

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['Url'], 'required'],
            [['File'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],
            [['Rel_User'], 'my_required'],
            [['Rel_Category'], 'my_required'],
            [['Views', 'Rel_User', 'Rel_Category', 'CreatedAt', 'UpdatedAt', 'IsDeleted', 'Id'], 'integer'],
            [['Image', 'Url', 'Caption'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['Url'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$/'],
            [['File'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'GIF'], 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,],
            [['CreatedAt', 'IsDeleted'], 'safe']
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom validation in model:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [      
     [['Rel_User, Rel_Category'], 'my_required'],
  ];
}

public function my_required($attribute_name, $params)
{
   if (empty($this->Rel_User) && empty($this->Rel_Category)) 
   {
     $this->addError($attribute_name, Yii::t('app', 'At least 1 of the field must be filled up properly'));

    return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081066/yii-form-model-validation-either-one-is-required)

Comment: hmm now it not required both of dropdownlists

Comment: i dont know why it not work or me I used this own rules before in other project and it work but now it not

Comment: no it not, mahybe it controller fail but thers ruels whcich i have there work fine i show You my controller

Comment: but i treid to move $model->validate() in all possible places and still not work

Comment: @qwerty. remove both fields from required rule.

Comment: i sorry i fix that :) so maybe You know where it can be a problem. I tried to use this funcion for example on other attribut and this still not work:`public function my_required($attribute_name, $params) {
        if (empty($this->Caption)) {
            $this->addError($attribute_name, Yii::t('app', 'Jedno z tych pól musi być wypełnione'));
        }
    }`